# Is there a way to trick an application into seeing a different display resolution?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

I work for a small NGO and we have a custom made application, which displays tables of data. On Windows 10 systems with two FHD monitors (3840x1080 resolution) the application works perfectly. The application is maximized on one screen and we can have tables with a lot of columns and the application provides horizontal scrolling which is double the size of the window (=3840 pixels).
However the same application on a single FHD monitor system (1920x1080 resolution) doesn't provide horizontal scrolling and instead resizes the columns so they become unreadable. Vendor support isn't forthcoming and so I'm wondering if I can trick the application on the single monitor system to behave as the dual monitor one.

I googled around and came across *GetSystemMetrics* specifically *SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN*. I was wondering if I could maybe load a dll to set the horizontal resolution to 3840 for the application? Has anyone done something like that? Does anyone know of a tool to set a per application resolution?

Comment: It may be possible for AMD and NVIDIA display adapters, but it will be for Windows entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid that's not an option, I don't want other applications to change behaviour, just this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a hexeditor and hardcoding the resolution in the app, but harrymc's suggestion is probably the best way to do it in a less hackish way.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to override the GetSystemMetrics API within a process,
here is a free product:
[WinAPIOverride](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/index.php).

From the description:

- You can hook functions inside the target process not only API
- You can easily override any API or any process internal function

(I have not used this product and cannot help with the details.)